# How to add positioning animation onstart in figma?

Tags: user-interface, user-experience, figma

I have a rectangle in figma and I want to give it a positioning animation from top to bottom on starting the page. (without clicking or hovering) How is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, the best way to animate in Figma is using a combination of **Smart Animate** & **After Delay** between two frames.

**On Run Animation**

We're going to create a start & end frame. Then, animate between them.

1. Create your starting frame with your rectangle in its starting position.
2. Rename the rectangle layer to something unique. This ensure the layer doesn't get missed with the Smart Animate function if the frame gets any busier with more layers.
3. Duplicate your frame `CMD+D` and position your rectangle to its end position (Check that Figma hasn't renamed your rectangle)
4. Click `Prototype` in the top right corner of your panel.
5. Select your starting frame & click the `None` dropdown & select `After Delay`
6. Click the `None` dropdown and select `Navigate To` from the list
7. In the dropdown the appears to the right, select your ending frame from the list
8. Under Animation, click the dropdown and select `Smart Animate`
9. Deselect your frame and ensure that the "Starting Frame" is set to your first frame.
10. Finally, hit play in the top right and watch the magic!

Hope this helps!

And here's a screenshot of the set up.

Hope this is what you were after!

[image: Figma Smart Animate]